# React components library and css modules

Tags: typescript, webpack, bundling-and-minification, css-modules

I have a problem where I can't figure out how to build my component library with css modules. I tried 2 approaches so far, the first using webpack and the second my custom build.

The problem with webpack is that I get a bundle eventually but I want to have every component to sit in a separate folder/file like as I have it my src folder. In terms of css modules webpack works perfectly.

The problem with my custom build is that I can't figure out how to handle css modules, I have an idea about gulp but without it do I have an option?

Also I use typescript in my project.